# Creating a zone following a route using Google map iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

For my current map based application, I need to have the following features on **Google Map iOS SDK**

1. User will select a **source** and a **destination**.
2. User will put a few **turning points** on the map to reach from **source** to **destination**.
3. User will also provide a width in meter.
4. Now using this **turning points** and width I need to create a zone as specified in the following hand made sketch.

[image]

I tried to create a polygon using [GMSMutablePath](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_polygon). User was also able to drag each marker and resize and reposition the zone.

[image]

I have also tried to understand [Create a hollow polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_polygon) *but could not find out a way to generate encoded string* to use in the following example code.

```
let hydePark = "tpwmEkd|y[QVe@Pk@BsHe@mGc@iNaAKMaBIYIq@qAMo@Eo@@[Fe@DoALu@HUb@c@XUZS^ELGxOhAd@@ZB`@J^BhFRlBN\\BZ@`AFrATAJAR?rAE\\C~BIpD"
let archibaldFountain = "tlvmEqq|y[NNCXSJQOB[TI"
let reflectionPool = "bewmEwk|y[Dm@zAPEj@{AO"

let polygon = GMSPolygon()
polygon.path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: hydePark)
polygon.holes = [GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: archibaldFountain)!, GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: reflectionPool)!]
```

In my exploration project, user was specifying the location coordinate, which I do not want. Rather user will just put the **turning points** on the maps and provide the **width** and the zone will be calculated automatically.

If there is any existing functionality from *GoogleMaps* SDK to achieve that? Or I need to follow a complex geometric calculation to draw the zone?

Answer (score 1):

Well I tried to do that, may be in a complicated way, but the problem was it self a complicated one.

Check this [repository](https://github.com/sauvikdolui/GMSExploration).

[image]